# DataBase Insert In Code Behind

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Trying to insert into db both text and images.  The only required fields are Category, Name, and Description.  If just those fields have entries, the insert into the db is not successful.  If the RecipePicture, which is NOT required is loaded the insert is successful. I am using SqlServer.

The problem has to be in the code behind but I cannot find it.  Any help would be appreciated as I need to be able to insert into db without inserting pictures/images.  The code behind:

```
 protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null
            && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {

                byte[] myimage = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
                HttpPostedFile Image = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                Image.InputStream.Read(myimage, 0,   (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AsianConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                SqlCommand storeimage = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AsianRecipe"
                 + "(Category, Name, Description, RecipePicture, RecipePictureType, RecipePictureSize, UserName, UserPicture, UserPictureType, UserPictureSize) "
                 + " values (@Category, @Name, @Description, @image, @imagetype, @imagesize, @UserName, @userpicture, @userpicturetype, @userpicturesize)", myConnection);
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, myimage.Length).Value = myimage;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@imagetype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value
                = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@imagesize", SqlDbType.BigInt, 99999).Value
                = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value
                = lblSelection.Text;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value
                = TextBox2.Text;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value
                = TextBox3.Text;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value
                = TextBox4.Text;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@userpicture", SqlDbType.VarBinary, myimage.Length).Value = myimage;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@userpicturetype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value
                = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentType;
                storeimage.Parameters.Add("@userpicturesize", SqlDbType.BigInt, 99999).Value
                = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength;




                myConnection.Open();
                storeimage.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConnection.Close();

            }
        }

        protected void OnSelect(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblSelection.Text = ((LinkButton)sender).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It kind of looks like your code no-ops if no `PostedFile` is present.

Comment: You have different casing in your parameters and your query. That might be a problem - C# is case-sensitive. Fix that and see if it helps.

Comment: Also, I don't see any IF statements to set the parameter properly when the picture isn't there. It's always set the same way, and that could cause an error. What is the value of "myImage" if it isn't filled in? And, you need to put the bytes of the image in the parameter, not the reference to the image itself. myImage.GetBytes() or something like that, depending on what type it is. Right now you're setting the value of the parameter to the image object itself, not the bytes within the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to create a stored procedure where you have optional params, and then in your code, you just add the params that are needed and have value for.  Otherwise, you would have to generate the sql and the params together, which imho would be a little messy.

I recommend you (1) create an sproc like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProc
(
@image              VarBinary = NULL,
@imagetype          VarChar(100) = NULL,
@imagesize          BigInt = NULL,
@category           NVarChar(50),
@name               NVarChar(100),
@description        NVarChar(50),
@username           NVarChar(50) = NULL,
@userpicture        VarBinary = NULL,
@userpicturetype    VarChar(100) = NULL,
@userpicturesize    BigInt = NULL
)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO AsianRecipe(Category, Name, [Description], RecipePicture, RecipePictureType, RecipePictureSize, UserName, UserPicture, UserPictureType, UserPictureSize)
    VALUES (@category, @name, @description, @image, @imagetype, @imagesize, @username, @userpicture, @userpicturetype, @userpicturesize)
```

Then (2) change your **UploadButton_Click** method like this, note that I've enclosed the execution into a a try/finally, to ensure the connection is closed, you may also use a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement if you prefer

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
    {

        byte[] myimage = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        HttpPostedFile Image = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        Image.InputStream.Read(myimage, 0, (int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AsianConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand storeimage = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProc", myConnection);
        if (myimage != null) { storeimage.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary, myimage.Length).Value = myimage; }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType)) { storeimage.Parameters.Add("@imagetype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType; }
        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0) { storeimage.Parameters.Add("@imagesize", SqlDbType.BigInt, 99999).Value = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength; }
        storeimage.Parameters.Add("@category", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = lblSelection.Text;
        storeimage.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        storeimage.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox4.Text)) { storeimage.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TextBox4.Text; }
        if (myimage != null) { storeimage.Parameters.Add("@userpicture", SqlDbType.VarBinary, myimage.Length).Value = myimage; }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentType)) { storeimage.Parameters.Add("@userpicturetype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentType; }
        if (FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0) { storeimage.Parameters.Add("@userpicturesize", SqlDbType.BigInt, 99999).Value = FileUpload2.PostedFile.ContentLength; }

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            storeimage.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Jason, I made an entirely new front and back page and used your exact code.  When I used the sproc, I got the error message, "sproc is expecting @category and none supplied".  If I take the sproc out and use the SqlCmd I used previously (my initial post) and I DO NOT  insert the two images, the page acts as though the data was inserted (I don't have error messages wired yet), but when I check the db, no insert was actually made.  If I enter both pictures, the insert is made into the db.  If I leave either of the pictures out, the insert will not happen.  I see nothing wrong with category.Thank

Comment: @user1830924 In your original post you said Category is one of the three required fields, thus it expects it.  If you don't want it, make it optional like the other params by changing your sproc and the c# code to skip the param if no data is available.

Comment: Jason, sorry for not being clear.  Category is required and I MADE an entry to insert category.  Only with the sproc, it comes back saying a @category is not supplied.  Using my original SqlCmd, and using all of your code except for the SqlCmd/Sproc, it does not do that and actually inserts into the db.  Would you give me your recommendations to: "changing your sproc and the c# code to skip the param if no data is available."  where a default/generic image will insert instead? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1830924 I reviewed the code, aside from some case mismatch that I unintentionally carried from your original post, it looks good.  Make the case fix, and give it a shot.  If it still doesn't work I can only suggest you try and run the sproc by itself through SSMS and do some debugging

Answer (score 0):

@Jason is right that a stored procedure can help separate your C# and SQL code, making it easier to debug. You should also consider using [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to "spy" on the SQL statement that is actually sent from C# to SQL Server. You might be able to see flaws in the SQL more clearly this way, and then go back into the C# to fix it. When using SQL Profiler, I recommend changing to the "Tuning" template in order to limit the data you are looking at; it should be easy to find that setting when create a new Trace.